# Django - Counting filtered model instances per row in a template table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Let's say I have the following django models:

```
class House(Model):
    author = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)
    title = CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    text = TextField(default='')
    rooms = IntegerField(null=True)

class Room(Model): 
    author = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)
    title = CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    text = TextField(default='')
    house = CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    furniture = IntegerField(null=True)

class Furniture(model): 
    author = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)
    title = CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    text = TextField(default='')
    room = CharField(max_length=200, default='')
```

And I want to generate the following table in a template:

| Room | In house | Amount of furniture |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Living Room | Summer house | 5 |
| Kitchen | Summer house | 8 |
| Bedroom | Summer house | 2 |
| Bathroom | Main house | 3 |

Where the column "Amount of furniture" counts the instances of the "furniture" model where the field "room" is equal to that of the entry in the column "room" for that row.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this, and I've landed on a few different ways - ranked from most ideal/pythonic to least ideal/pythonic.

1. Building some sort of mechanism into the model. This would be perfect, but I can't seem to find any obvious way to do it.
2. Adding a function that generates a dictionary in the view in views.py. Would be easy to build (gather names of "room", make a for loop doing a filter query for each room on the model "furniture", add a counter variable, and build a dictionary) but not very flexible or pythonic.
3. Using a third party module like datatables. Feels like overkill - but may be a better long term solution?
4. Setting up some real shenaningans in the template language. Since you can't declare variables in the template, i imagine this would be a spider web of nested loops, conditionals, and custom template tags.

Which approach should I go for here?

Comment: Why are there no `ForeignKey`s from `Furniture` to `Room` and from `Room` to `House`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should work a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ForeignKey) to link models. This is part of [*database normalization* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to prevent *data duplication* and making databases more manageable:

```
class House(Model):
    author = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)
    title = CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    text = TextField(default='')

class Room(Model): 
    author = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)
    title = CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    text = TextField(default='')
    house = ForeignKey(House, on_delete=CASCADE)

class Furniture(model): 
    author = ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE)
    title = CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    text = TextField(default='')
    room = ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

there is also no need to store the number of `Room`s or `Furniture`: you can determine that when necessary. In your view you can query the `Room` model with:

```
from app_name.models import Room
from django.db.models import Count

def some_view(request):
    rooms = Room.objects.select_related('house').annotate(
        num_furniture=Count('furniture')
    )
    return render(request, 'app_name/some_template.html', {'rooms': rooms})
```

here we thus annotate the `Room`s with the number of related `Funiture` with `Count('furniture')`. The database will simply count the number of `Furniture`s per `Room`: this is more robust since it does not require logic when creating, updating, removing a `Furniture`, `Room`, etc.

and in the template, you then can render the table with:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Room</th><th>In house</th><th>Amount of furniture</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for room in rooms %}
    <tr><td>{{ room.title }}</td><td>{{ room.house.title }}</td><td>{{ room.num_furniture }}</td></tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Where would I add the author filter for rooms in the view?

Comment: @LarsLill: add `.filter(author=request.user)` at the end of the queryset.